# Not able to identify elements on android emulator using selenium webdriver

Tags: android-emulator, selenium-webdriver

I have created a sample application where in I have opened google.com and have entered some text in textbox.

Application is able to open google.com but unable to identify elements.

Sample App:

public void testGoogle() throws Exception {

```
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
      capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();

      WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(capabilities);

    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");

    Thread.sleep(4000);

    // Find the text input element by its name
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0"));


    // Enter something to search for
    element.sendKeys("Welcome");

    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
    element.submit();

    // Check the title of the page
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
  }
```

Can you please help?

I am using android emulator and selenium webdriver.

Thanks,
Harsh

Comment: Please share the exception

Answer (score 2):

```
public void testGoogle() throws Exception {          
           WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");

        Thread.sleep(4000);

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));


        element.sendKeys("Welcome");

          element.submit();     
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit(); 
}
```

i have change only the find.element section and remove the desired capability , it working fine now